# How to make Firefox warn on quit even if only one tab exist?

Tags: firefox

How can I make Firefox 52 warn on quit even if only one tab exists?

`browser.showQuitWarning` and `browser.warnOnQuit` is set to `true`,but they seem not work for the "only one tab" situation

Comment: There's also a browser.tabs.warnonClose that should be set to true.  Is the behavior the same whether you quit from the File menu or Ctrl-Q or the Close X icon?

Comment: You do not get the "Save & Quit" dialog if you choose "Show my windows and tabs from last time".   So apparently, this is by design if you are using that option.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm set to "Show my home page",`browser.tabs.warnonClose` is true as default. "Is the behavior the same whether you quit from the File menu or Ctrl-Q or the Close X icon?" seem all quit way get same behavior.

Comment: Do you have startup set to show windows and tabs from the last session?

Comment: "Do you have startup set to show windows and tabs from the last session?"I'm set to "Show my home page"  in startup.

Comment: As far as I can tell, we've covered all the bases of how it is supposed to work.  This issue has been a periodic problem with FF going back to 2011 or earlier.  Every so many years, the issue reappears, either as a bug or a change in how FF operates.  I didn't find reports specific to V52, but I suspect that the problem is back.  You're already doing everything the way it is supposed to work; I couldn't find any other workarounds or solutions.  It can't hurt, though, to download the latest 52 ESR and try replacing your installation (can be done without losing your profile if you need to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted the question in the previous answer.  I'll leave it in place in case it's helpful to others landing here.

If you just want to get a warning when you try to quit with only one tab open, Firefox won't do that, unfortunately.  It only warns if multiple tabs are open, regardless of warning settings.

If you accidentally quit with just one open tab, you would need to restore it from `History` in the next session.

Answer (score 2):

The "closing with last tab" issue is handled a different way.  Rather than issuing a warning, you directly control the behavior.

In `about:config`, go to **`browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab`** and set it to `false`.

If you delete the last tab, Firefox will remain open and will create a replacement tab with whatever your new tab provision defines.  This prevents accidentally closing Firefox, but it also means that closing the tab is no longer a method for quiting Firefox.  You will need to use one of the explicit close provisions (i.e., via menu, window "X", shortcut key, etc.).